# How to use .rdlc and ReportViewer with Page template in wpf?

Tags: wpf, rdlc, reportviewer

I am working with WPF and i want to create reports from my collection, but i am unable to load ReportViewer in Page template, as you know all in Windows template we can easily use ReportViewer but if you are using Page template within Frame in Windows template than ReportViewer does not work.

So do you have any idea how can i use ReportViewer in Page (loads in Frame) 
in following code i can easily load ReportViwer due to Windows template

```
<Window x:Class="WpfReportApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
  <WindowsFormsHost> 
    <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="_reportViewer"/> 
  </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

I want to use ReportViewer in following template.

```
<Page x:Class="WpfReportApplication.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms"
<Grid>
  <WindowsFormsHost> 
    <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="_reportViewer"/> 
  </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Template within Windows Template. My page flow like below.

```
<Window> template --> Frame (Control) --> Loading <Page> template (using FrameNavigationService(new Page()) from MainWindows.xaml.cs.
```

I tried some links but those all for windows template not for page template.

Any suggestion/solution highly appreciated.